# CasperJS / PhantomJS hanging on casper.start on localhost when connected online

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a simple CasperJS test asserting an http status of 200 on http://localhost:3000. It works as expected (fast) if I am NOT connected to the outside network, but if I turn on Wifi, it takes 1-3 minutes to return a test result. Connecting to http://localhost:3000 in my browser works fine regardless of internet connection.

The Casper logging/debugging features have not revealed any clues.

Any ideas what could be going on?

**Update**
If I run Charles Proxy, and connect to the network... IT WORKS! So, something about the way Charles is intercepting things is fixing the issue. Hmm.

Comment: Does your page reference remote resources?

Comment: Nope. Strange, I know.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I was wrong about remote resources. We ARE loading some external JS, and if I remove them, the problem goes away. Still running Charles fixes the issue... so I suspect something is up with my network or machine :(  Any ideas?

Comment: It may be some bug with PhantomJS. See if you can update to version 2 (you will also need to use CasperJS from git in that case).